# Validacion de campos

Tags: django

mi pregunta tal vez sea muy simple, pero como puedo validar que en un campo numérico solo puedan agregar números positivo y con una extensión especifica (longitud).
Disculpen las molestias, gracias

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Personal(models.Model):

OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES = (
    ('Masculino', 'Masculino'),
    ('Femenino', 'Femenino'),
)
OPCIONES_ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES = (
    ('Casado(a)', 'Casado(a)'),
    ('Soltero(a)', 'Soltero(a)'),
    ('Viudo(a)', 'Viudo(a)')
)
OPCIONES_GRADO_INSTRUCCION_CHOICES = (
    ('Bachiller', 'Bachiller'),
    ('Universitaria', 'Universitaria'),
    ('Tecnico Superior', 'Tecnico superior'),
    ('Tecnico Medio', 'Tecnico Medio')
)
OPCIONES_CARGO_CHOICES = (
    ('Director(a)', 'Director(a)'),
    ('Analista', 'Analista'),
    ('Supervisor(a)', 'Supervisor(a)'),
    ('Empleado(a)','Empleado(a)'),
    ('Seguridad','Seguridad'),
    ('Supervisor seguridad', 'Supervisor de Seguridad'),
    ('Contratado(a)', 'Contratado(a)'),
    ('Obrero(a)', 'Obrero(a)')        
)

codigo_empleado = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
ci = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=OPCIONES_CARGO_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)       
creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
genero = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=OPCIONES_GENERO_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True) 
email = models.EmailField()
telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)        
direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
grado_instruccion = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=OPCIONES_GRADO_INSTRUCCION_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
numero_de_hijos = models.IntegerField()
fecha_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s'% (self.nombre)
```

Este es mi model.py

python 3.5

Comment: podemos ver tu codigo? que version de python y django estas utilizando

Comment: agrega como estas realizando tu formulario .. forms.py... o html...

Comment: dos opciones buenas , si usas serializer tambien te quedaria mejor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a suponer que quieres validar este campo

```
numero_de_hijos = models.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_length=2, min_length=2)
```

Con min_value es un atributo donde se específica el valor mínimo que puede se puede ingresar, al poner a cero solo aceptará números positivos y con min y Max length el tamaño mínimo y máximo que acepta el input , al tener ambos atributos el mismo valor solo aceptará que ingresen un número de dos dígitos

Answer (score 1):

te sugiero que leas la documentación de Django que es [positiveintegerfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) o [positivesmallintegerfield](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield)

Puedes arreglar tu modelo poniendo alguno de estos tipos.